# Реализация выпадающих блоков на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, события

Добрый день, нужно реализовать выпадающие блоки в верстке (сразу говорю в js/jquery разбираюсь на уровне начинающего), есть блок с фото краткой инфой и ссылкой (стрелочкой вниз) при нажатии на стрелочку блок будет увеличиваться и раскрывать еще больше информации. Думал реализовать все это добавлением класса с увеличенной высотой по нажатию на стрелку. Вот таким вот способом:

```
$(".select").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".select-element").toggleClass("add-height");
});
```

Но возник баг что класс с высотой применяется ко всем элементам и получается что они все едут. Нужен другой вариант реализации jquery функции. Подскажите возможные пути решения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если блок `.select-element` вложен в `.select`, то стоит попробовать использовать `this`:

```
$(".select").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this для указания на нажатый элемент
    // closest для поиска ближайшего родителя
    $(this).closest(".select-element").toggleClass("add-height");
});
```

Comment: Там все немного иначе, блок "select-element" это обертка а "select" это кнопка внутри этой обертки (получается что при нажатии на кнопку к обертке добавляется класс который увеличивает ее высоту), и это не первый опыт с использованием this и он почему то не хочет с ним работать, может что то с логикой не так?

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev поправил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо тебе, очень выручил. Уже хотел делать на основе аккордеона без js.